# mysql query if there is no record or record.xx != xx trouble with query

Tags: mysql, search

I've 3 MYSQL tables.

"villa" table has records for properties.
"villa_type" table has records for property types.
"villa_price" table for daily prices with dates, price, property id and availability columns.

I receive all data with SQL, left join it with villa_type table to receive some additional info about property which works ok, and left join the table with the 3rd table to ask if the property is booked on that date or available.

Query is like this.

```
 SELECT villa.*, villa_type.tip as villatypename 
 FROM villa
 LEFT JOIN villa_type on villa_type.id = villa.type
 LEFT JOIN villa_price on villa_price.villaid = villa.id
 WHERE villa.lang = 1 
 AND villa.area = 1980
 AND villa.status = 1 
 AND villa.status2 = 1
 -- Problem starts here..............
 AND (villa_price.vdate = '2015-01-13' OR villa_price.vdate is null)
 AND (
       ((villa_price.condition != 2) AND (villa_price.condition != 3))
       OR (villa_price.condition is null)
     )
```

The problem is: if the villa has a record for 2015-01-13 and its condition is 2 or 3, i correctly don't get that villa listed (which is what i'm trying to do), but if that villa has a record for that same date and the condition is 1, it still doesn't get listed (while it should).

I simply want to check villa_price table to see that villa has a condition of 2 or 3 for the given date and eliminate that villa from result.

Any help or guide will be appreciated. Thanks alot

Comment: What are you trying to do here: `left join villa_price on villa_price.villaid = villa.id`?

Comment: matching the id of the villa with villa id on the price table

Comment: Sorry. I misread it.

Comment: you may want to prepare an sqlfiddle with table schema and minimal data to reproduce the problem

Comment: `and its condition is 2 OR 3` I see in your sql !=2 AND !=3

Comment: yes if the condition for the villa on the given date is 2 or 3 it shouldn't be listed, i need to receive the ones with condition of 1 or if there is no record for that id (or for that date)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/138494/1 sqlfiddle its strange because it seems fine on the sqlfiddle